# Failed to update auto layout status / Failed to render instance

Tags: objective-c

I try to run friend old app that written in objective c .

my friend develop this in Xcode 5 ,I try to run this app in 7.3.1 .

I get this error:

file:///Users/myname/Desktop/myapp%20test%201/after%20coca%20update/myapp/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: The agent raised a "NSInternalInconsistencyException" exception: Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'myappStepper'

file:///Users/myname/Desktop/myapp%20test%201/after%20coca%20update/myapp/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of myappStepper: The agent threw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this with change in myappStepper.xib "Open in" from Xcode 5.0 to Xcode 6.0.
Like the storyboard.xib.

[image]